# Disable translation of watchdog messages

Tags: i18n-l10n, log-messages

i have problem with drupal.
I'm using the watchdog function to save some log messages, but when i go to read them in the admin panel (admin/reports/dblog) they get detected by the T function and so i have a lot of unnecessary log entries inside the translate content page. Is there a way to disable the detection for that page?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. The watchdog report page is driven by [`dblog_overview()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.admin.inc/function/dblog_overview/7.x) which utilizes the theme function [`theme_dblog_message()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!dblog!dblog.admin.inc/function/theme_dblog_message/7.x) to render the message columns.

If you override the function, you can alter the arguments for [`t()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21bootstrap.inc/function/t/7.x) so that `$options = array('langcode' => 'en')` which will make `t()` ignore it for translation.

For example, if you defined a `mytheme_dblog_message()` within your theme's **template.php**:

```
function mytheme_dblog_message($variables) {
  $output = '';
  $event = $variables['event'];
  // Check for required properties.
  if (isset($event->message) && isset($event->variables)) {
    // Messages without variables or user specified text.
    if ($event->variables === 'N;') {
      $output = $event->message;
    }
    // Message to translate with injected variables.
    else {
      // Add langcode = 'en' to prevent translation
      $output = t($event->message, unserialize($event->variables), array('langcode' => 'en'));

    }
    if ($variables['link'] && isset($event->wid)) {
      // Truncate message to 56 chars.
      $output = truncate_utf8(filter_xss($output, array()), 56, TRUE, TRUE);
      $output = l($output, 'admin/reports/event/' . $event->wid, array('html' => TRUE));
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made it like this:

```
function MYADMINTHEME_dblog_message($variables) {
  $output = '';
  $event = $variables['event'];
  // Check for required properties.
  if (isset($event->message) && isset($event->variables)) {
    // Messages without variables or user specified text.
    if ($event->variables === 'N;') {
      $output = $event->message;
    }
    // Message to translate with injected variables.
    else {
      $output = format_string($event->message, unserialize($event->variables));
    }
    if ($variables['link'] && isset($event->wid)) {
      // Truncate message to 56 chars.
      $output = truncate_utf8(filter_xss($output, array()), 56, TRUE, TRUE);
      $output = l($output, 'admin/reports/event/' . $event->wid, array('html' => TRUE));
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```